# Selection data from sqlite database with cursor

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor

I'm trying to select data from SQLite database but have troubles.
First, i'm load database from assets folder to data/data/PACKAGE_NAME/databases. It loads fine and database loads correctly. But when i'm trying to read data with cursor - application stops( Here is my code, point to my mistakes pls. Thanks.

```
public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

public static final String DB_NAME = "cards";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public static final String TABLE_CARDS = "cards";

public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_CARD_NAME = "card_name";
public static final String COLUMN_TYPE = "type";
public static final String COLUMN_RARITY = "rarity";
public static final String COLUMN_CARD_CLASS = "card_class";
public static final String COLUMN_SET = "card_set";
public static final String COLUMN_RACE = "race";
public static final String COLUMN_SKILLS = "skills";
public static final String COLUMN_MANA = "mana";
public static final String COLUMN_ATTACK = "attack";
public static final String COLUMN_HEALTH = "health";
public static final String COLUMN_DAMAGE = "damage";
public static final String COLUMN_DURABILITY = "durability";
public static final String COLUMN_CRAFT = "craft";
public static final String COLUMN_DUST = "dust";
public static final String COLUMN_ARTIST = "artist";
public static final String COLUMN_EXTRA_INFO = "extra_info";
public static final String COLUMN_CARD_SRC = "card_src";


public SQLiteHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

public List<FullCard> getCards() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

    //I want to record all selected data to this list
    List<FullCard> cards = new ArrayList<FullCard>();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(SQLiteHelper.TABLE_CARDS,
            null, null, null, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        FullCard card = cursorToCard(cursor);
        cards.add(card);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return cards;
}
private FullCard cursorToCard(Cursor cursor) {
    FullCard card = new FullCard();
    card.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
    card.setCardName(cursor.getString(1));
    card.setType(cursor.getString(2));
    card.setRarity(cursor.getString(3));
    card.setCardClass(cursor.getString(4));
    card.setSet(cursor.getString(5));
    card.setRace(cursor.getString(6));
    card.setSkills(cursor.getString(7));
    card.setMana(cursor.getString(8));
    card.setAttack(cursor.getString(9));
    card.setHealth(cursor.getString(10));
    card.setDamage(cursor.getString(11));
    card.setDurability(cursor.getString(12));
    card.setCraft(cursor.getString(13));
    card.setDust(cursor.getString(14));
    card.setArtist(cursor.getString(15));
    card.setExtraInfo(cursor.getString(16));
    card.setCard_src(cursor.getString(17));
    return card;
}
```

}

Fragment of class, where i call method getCards() and it cause app crash.

```
public class ActivityDB extends ListActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private SQLiteHelper datasource;
private static Parcelable state;
private static ListView lv;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_db);

    Button button_filters = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_filters);
    Button button_menu = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_menu);
    button_filters.setOnClickListener(this);
    button_menu.setOnClickListener(this);

    ListItem listItem;
    ArrayList<ListItem> listItems = new ArrayList<ListItem>();

    datasource = new SQLiteHelper(this); 
    List<FullCard> dbCardList = datasource.getCards(); // Here is that method

    for (FullCard aDbCardList : dbCardList) {
        listItem = new ListItem();
        listItem.setTitle(aDbCardList.getCardName());
        listItem.setPar1(aDbCardList.getMana());
        listItem.setPar2(aDbCardList.getAttack());
        listItem.setPar3(aDbCardList.getHealth());
        listItems.add(listItem);
    }

    setListAdapter(new ListItemAdapter(this,listItems));
```

}

Here is logcat errors:
09-29 01:54:11.989 I/SQLiteAssetHelper(15846): successfully opened database cards
09-29 01:54:12.049 W/dalvikvm(15846): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
09-29 01:54:12.069 E/AndroidRuntime(15846): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-29 01:54:12.069 E/AndroidRuntime(15846): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.FHS/com.FHS.ActivityDB}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unknown error: Unable to convert BLOB to string
09-29 01:54:12.069 E/AndroidRuntime(15846):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
09-29 01:54:12.069 E/AndroidRuntime(15846):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
09-29 01:54:12.069 E/AndroidRuntime(15846):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
09-29 01:54:12.069 E/AndroidRuntime(15846):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
09-29 01:54:12.069 E/AndroidRuntime(15846):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-29 01:54:12.069 E/AndroidRuntime(15846):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
09-29 01:54:12.069 E/AndroidRuntime(15846):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
09-29 01:54:12.069 E/AndroidRuntime(15846):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-29 01:54:12.069 E/AndroidRuntime(15846):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-29 01:54:12.069 E/AndroidRuntime(15846):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
09-29 01:54:12.069 E/AndroidRuntime(15846):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
09-29 01:54:12.069 E/AndroidRuntime(15846):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-29 01:54:12.069 E/AndroidRuntime(15846): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unknown error: Unable to convert BLOB to string
09-29 01:54:12.069 E/AndroidRuntime(15846):     at android.database.CursorWindow.getString_native(Native Method)
09-29 01:54:12.069 E/AndroidRuntime(15846):     at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:361)
09-29 01:54:12.069 E/AndroidRuntime(15846):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:49)
09-29 01:54:12.069 E/AndroidRuntime(15846):     at com.FHS.SQLiteHelper.cursorToCard(SQLiteHelper.java:84)
09-29 01:54:12.069 E/AndroidRuntime(15846):     at com.FHS.SQLiteHelper.getCards(SQLiteHelper.java:73)
09-29 01:54:12.069 E/AndroidRuntime(15846):     at com.FHS.ActivityDB.onCreate(ActivityDB.java:65)
09-29 01:54:12.069 E/AndroidRuntime(15846):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-29 01:54:12.069 E/AndroidRuntime(15846):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
09-29 01:54:12.069 E/AndroidRuntime(15846):     ... 11 more
09-29 01:54:23.589 W/InputManagerService(207): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 15846 uid 10062

Comment: Please share your logcat errors.

Comment: @PushkarPandey Edit post with logcat, it says unable to convert BLOB to string

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, forget that last answer. After reading again I saw I was wrong. There is a line in your logcat that says:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(15846): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unknown error: Unable to convert BLOB to string 09-29 01:54:12.069 E/AndroidRuntime(15846): at android.database.CursorWindow.getString_native(Native Method) 09-29 01:54:12.069
```

Have you defined some column as a blob?

---

<del>`SQLiteHelper.TABLE_CARDS` should be the second argument in `SQliteDatabase.query()`, and not the first:

    public Cursor query (String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy)</del>

Comment: em...TABLE_CARDS represent table name in database, so, according your code above, table name should be first. Am i right?

Comment: no, _id column defined as integer primary key, and all other columns are text. Some of fields are null.

Comment: problem solved. there was an issue whith contetn of database. some strings are filled with (data), and it case exception.